# Threats that JavaScript poses to a web crawler

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler

I'm writing a simple crawler with node.js, which searches for web pages and conditionally executes any JavaScript present.

The problem is that in doing so, I execute code form untrusted sources in my node.js environment. Can running untrusted code on node.js in such a way be dangerous (i.e. when encountering malicious scripts), and, if so, how do I act on this?

Code is executed by [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom)

Comment: it will depend on how you code your crawler. You are basically asking, "what could a malicious site do to my custom client that I have not finished yet?" And that's a little like asking "how long is a piece of string?"

Comment: The question is too broad. You are asking how to code your project securely. There are entire libraries of tips. Please look up OWASP as a start .

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138511/discussion-on-question-by-trashbinnp2019-threats-that-javascript-poses-to-a-web).